# In a custom NodeJS package, how to perform unit testing on a function that depends on functions in the same package?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am a newbie in unit testing.

I am performing unit testing on each function in my custom NodeJS package.
Suppose that my package exports functions as follows,

```
//my-package.js
module.exports = {
    listFiles,
    copyFiles
}

/**
 * @return <list> a list of files under src_dir
 */
function listFiles(src_dir){
    //stat all files under src_dir and make a list containing all file names
    ...
}

/**
 * @param [allowed_ext] a list of file extensions
 */
function copyFiles(src_dir, dst_dir, allowed_ext = []){
    //filter files under src_dir according to allowed_ext
    var files = listFiles(src_dir).filter(function(){...})

    for(var a_file of files){
        //other operations on each single file
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to do unit test on both `listFiles()` and `copyFiles()`; however, `copyFiles()` actually depends on `listFiles()`. What is the best practice to write a unit test for these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few option that you can choose:

1. You can test listFiles independently and then test copyFiles (that uses listFiles)
2. You can test listFiles and then test copyFiles with a mocked version of listFiles injected somehow (there are few ways to do that)
3. You could test copyFiles only if those tests also cover the listFiles in 100%

I would personally recommend doing a mix of 1 and 2.

Now, as to how to do that - if you e.g. use Jasmine you can create a mocked functions with spies:

- https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

To mock require statements you could use mock-require:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require

And I always recommend using a coverage tool like nyc or istanbul:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul

In some of my projects I enforce 100% coverage as a part of `npm test` and it works pretty well to make sure that everything is tested extensively.

Hint: It will be easier to mock the functions used by other functions if every one of them is in its own file but it's not the only way to do that.

Comment: I'm using `sinon.stub(require('my-package'), 'listFiles')` to mock `listFiles()` for testing `copyFiles()`; however, `sinon.stub` only affects the exported object while the reference of `listFiles` in `copyFiles()` is still pointing to the original `listFiles()`. Is it a good practice to rewrite the module exporting in the following way and use `myModule.listFiles()` in `copyFiles()`?

Comment: `const myModule = module.exports = {listFiles, copyFiles}`